# All the currents and voltages are shown zero in my circuit - Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: integrated-circuit, simulation, error, virtuoso

In the following circuit, I do not know why all the currents and voltages are shown zero?

[image]

My simulation just contains the "DC" simulation. After performing DC simulation, all the node voltages are zero and specially the nodes connecting to the supply that definitely have a nonzero voltage. Does not matter how to choose the size of transistors. With and without the resistor, nothing change. No need to mention that I had changed the cell and library already, but nothing changed.

Comment: When you ran "Check and Save", were any warnings printed to the Command Interpreter Window (CIW)? If so, what were they?

Comment: hello. no error, no warning, successful simulation. but wrong result!!!

Comment: The cause is your 0 vgs voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view name of all the components must be "symbol". Otherwise, this error may happen to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you have low or not specified resistance on R5. Your Vgs is close to threshold and you can see that in specification when Vgs = threshold voltage current flowing through MOSFET is super low (typically few microamps). Try to increase your load resistance value or increase voltage at source V1.